# To sort Table in Javascript

Tags: javascript, tablesort

I have a situation where I need to sort table values based on the click on table headers. I did look at the examples using `sortTable()` but I'm not sure of how to call the function in javascript. I build the table in javascript using the below statement

```
content += "<table  border='1' style='width:1000px' id='AnnouncementTable'>";
```

where `content` is a JS variable. But for some reason I'm not able to get the `sortTable()` called. Could anyone help me in resolving the issue ?

Regards,

Comment: Does this question actually have anything to do with sorting tables? It seems as though you are having problems getting a function to run on click.

Answer (score 0):

You will need these 3 tools for this task.  Your overall format would be to grab the button that the user is clicking using a query selector.  Add an 'on click' type of event listener.  Run a function that would handle, or run on click.

- [Event Listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [Query Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- [Event Handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers)